# Python requests парсинг кириллицы

Tags: python, кодировка, парсер, requests

Пытаюсь спарсить сайт и записать данные в CSV. Все работает, но данные кладутся в файл в таком виде `\u041a\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043a\u0430\u0436\u0434\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0434\u043e 3-\u0445 \u043c\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u043e\u043d\u043e\u0432`

Если добавить `encode('utf-8')` - сохраняется текст в нужной кодировке, но обрезается при первом же HTML теге, например, когда в тексте встречается перенос `<br>` или какой ни будь `<strong>`

мой код

```
# coding: utf8
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
import csv

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17"
}

csvfile = open('credit-listing.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

i = 1

while i < 2:
    url = requests.get("http://credit-board.ru/index.php?page=search&sCategory=116&iPage={}".format(i), headers=headers)
    page_html = fromstring(url.content)
    all_listings = page_html.xpath('//*[@id="listing-card-list"]/li')
    listings_list = []
    for listing in all_listings:
        listing_urls = listing.xpath('./div/div/div/div/a/@href')[0]
        listing_request = requests.get(listing_urls)
        listing_html = fromstring(listing_request.content)
        listing_title = listing_html.xpath('//*[@id="item-content"]/h1/strong/text()')
        listing_text = listing_html.xpath('//*[@id="description"]/p[1]/text()')
        listing_meta = listing_html.xpath('//*[@id="custom_fields"]/div/div/text()')
        listings_list.append([listing_title, listing_text, listing_meta])
        writer.writerow([listing_title[0].encode('utf-8'), listing_text[0].encode('utf-8'), listing_meta[0].encode('utf-8')])
    i+=1
    print i
```

Не пойму, как парсить весь текст и сохранять его в нормальной кодировке?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ответ исчерпывающий, однако, появилась новая ошибка.

Comment: Если ошибка другого типа, наилучшим путем будет публикация нового вопроса, со ссылкой на текущие, если это необходимо.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, у вас в строках, которые вы пытаетесь сохранить в `csv`, есть символы перевода строки и табуляции. Во-вторых, встречаются запятые, которые по-умолчанию в `csv` используются в качестве разделителей колонок. Поэтому, перед записью от спецсимволов нужно избавиться, и включить экранирование строк. Но лучше всего обернуть записываемые строки в `base64`, чтобы не было никаких конфликтов ни с кодировкой, ни со спецсимволами.

Чтобы включить экранирование строк, надо делать так:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Чтобы закодировать в `base64` - вот так:

```
import base64

...

writer.writerow([
    base64.b64encode(listing_title[0].encode('utf-8')),
    base64.b64encode(listing_text[0].encode('utf-8')),
    base64.b64encode(listing_meta[0].encode('utf-8'))
])
```

При чтении из `csv`, перед использованием, строки надо будет раскодировать при помощи `base64.b64decode`. Примерно так:

```
with open('credit-listing.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    rows = []
    for row in reader:
        cols = []
        for col in row:
            cols.append(base64.b64decode(col).decode('utf-8'))
        rows.append(cols)
    print rows
```

Comment: Дает такую ошибку   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/credit_parser.py", line 29, in <module>
    writer.writerow([base64.b64decode(listing_title[0].encode('utf-8')), base64.b64decode(listing_text[0].encode('utf-8')), base64.b64decode(listing_meta[0].encode('utf-8'))])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding

Comment: Вы неправильно код из примера скопировали. Надо использовать b64encode при записи в csv, а не b64decode.